# How do I fix my datetime command in my Discord Bot?

Tags: python, datetime, heroku, discord.py

I've recently began to learn about Discord Bots and tried to make one myself, I've got some basics working but haven't been able to get a new section of the code working which is supposed to get the current datetime and was wondering what I've done wrong.

Edit: This is currently hosted on Heroku so I have no idea how to check for errors

```
import discord
from datetime import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member.name} has joined the server')
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(745404752161931266)
    print(channel)
    await channel.send(f'{member.name} has joined the server')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member.name} has left the server')
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(745404752161931266)
    print(channel)
    await channel.send(f'{member.name} has left the server')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(765757497155649567)
    if message.content.find("!hello") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    if message.content.find("!datetime") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("date and time =", dt_string)
        
client.run('[my_token]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have more than one the same listener, you have to put your whole code in one

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        # ...
    elif message.content.startswith('!datetime'):
        # ...
```

A better alternative to that is using [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot), here's an example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!')

# To invoke: `!hello`

bot.run('token')
```

> This class is a subclass of discord.Client and as a result anything that you can do with a discord.Client you can do with this bot.

But if you really wanna stick with `discord.Client` you can create custom events with `client.dispatch('name of the event', *args)` sadly there's no docs about it.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        # Dispatching the custom event
        client.dispatch('hello', message)


@client.event
async def on_hello(message):
    """Notice how the event it's called `on_hello` not `hello` and
    takes the same arguments that we specified in `client.dispatch`"""
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Also to check the logs from your heroku app:

```
heroku logs -a {name of the app} 
or
heroku logs -a {name of the app} --tail
```

Comment: You can use also `@client.listen("on_message")` as the decorator and then call your function a different name. That way you can have multiple `on_message` events